# What does it mean when a light bulb appears over someone's head?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Sometimes in multiplayer in Black Ops, I see a lightbulb appear over another player's head. What does that indicate?

Comment: ...in comics, that means they had an idea. Given the context, I'd guess the idea is absorbing as many bullets as they possibly can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's when the player has paused their game. Obviously, you can't *actually* pause a multiplayer game, but it's when they are on menus and can't move/shoot.

As far as I can tell this is limited to the use of the start menu (change class, leave game) and associated system menus - for example, the Xbox Dashboard.

Comment: In other words ... "free kill".

Comment: @Anon I'm not sure, I think it's limited to your own teammates, but I didn't include it in the answer because I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I've never seen this anywhere but on teammates. And does this include changing settings in the start menu? (I semi-commonly will change sensitivity depending on how I'm feeling)

Comment: @Earlz Yes, anything in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

It means that they are typing or talking.

Comment: I thought that, too, but I don't always hear any voice from them when the light bulb is up.

Comment: it comes up when they're typing, because they cannot play the game while they're typing, but they can whiel talking.